# Getting first 5 even numbers element from vector after reverse const iteration

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code below that generates 15 random integers and uses them to initialize  my vector, `intVec`. What I'm trying to do here is to iterate through the vector in reverse order and only print out the first 5 even numbers encountered while iterating.

I tried using the erase method to just print the first 5 elements but it keeps throwing me an exception error that says:

> can't decrement vector iterator before begin

One of the requirements is that I have to use the `const_reverse_iterator`. Is there any simpler way to accomplish this?

```
 int main()
    {
    default_random_engine randObj;
    vector<int> intVec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        intVec.push_back(randObj());
    }
    
    vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator iter;
    for (iter = intVec.rbegin(); iter < intVec.rend(); ++iter) 
    {
        if (*iter % 2 == 0)
        {
            intVec.erase(intVec.begin()+5, intVec.end());
            cout << *iter << endl;
        }
    }
 };
```

Comment: _"what I'm trying to do here is to iterate through the vector in reverse order and only print out the first 5 even numbers"_  Why does that require you to erase anything?  It is not clear what your `intVec.erase` line is trying to do, but it introduces several bugs.

Comment: You're erasing 10 elements when first encountering an element divisible by 2. This does invalidate the iterator `iter` you're using, at least assuming find one match during the first 10 checks...

Comment: I was thinking that I could just remove whatever element there is from position 5 to the end of the vector after getting the even numbers.

Comment: _"after getting the even numbers"_  Are you sure this `erase` occurs "after getting the even numbers"?  It looks like you are doing it **before** trying print the **first** even number.  And you are likely deleting the even number that you have not yet printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement of having to use the `const_reverse_iterator` (note the "const") should be telling you that modifying the vector is not allowed. And nor is it even necessary: just use that iterator and run through the vector, printing out the elements that are even and, when doing so, incrementing a "counter" variable. When (or, technically, "if") that counter reaches 5, you can break out of the loop.

Note also that the `const_reverse_iterator` functions are `crbegin()` and `crend()`.

Like this, for example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine randObj;
    std::vector<unsigned> intVec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        intVec.push_back(randObj());
    }

    int count = 0;
    std::vector<unsigned>::const_reverse_iterator iter;
    for (iter = intVec.crbegin(); iter != intVec.crend(); ++iter) {
        if (*iter % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << *iter << "\n";
            if (++count == 5) break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this method is really simple and helpful.